# How to write Image file into binary field of OpenERP using API

Tags: python, api, rest, odoo, bottle

I created an api using python bottle for accessing OpenERP REST API.

My problem is while uploading a image file and writing it into the binary field in OpenERP

it throws  raise TypeError, "cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled"

Here I uploaded my code

```
from bottle import get, post, run,request,error,route,template
@route('/')
def index():
   return'''Welcome'''


@error(500)
def custom500(error):
   return 'Error while validating data.'

# Advisor Creation Start #

@get('/advisor') # or @route('/advisor')

def advisor_form():
    form ='''<form method="POST" action="/advisor" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Photo:<input name="photo" type="file"/><br>
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>'''
    return form

@post('/advisor') # or @route('/advisor', method='POST')
def advisor_submit():
   import xmlrpclib
   username = 'uname'
   pwd = 'pwd'      
   dbname = 'db'    

   photo  = request.files.get('photo')
   print photo,"L:K<:L"
   sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
   try:
      uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)
   except("Error username or password"):
      print "sock_common error"
   sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')
   res={
     'consultant_photo':photo
   }

   advisor_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.advisor', 'create', res)
   return 'Advisor Created!'
   # Advisor Creation End #
 run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are the things you have to do before the uploaded file is ready to send to OpenERP

get the file pointer

```
photo  = request.files.get('photo')
```

read the file data

```
photo_data = photo.file.read()
```

encode with base64

```
base64.b64encode(photo_data)
```

Now you can pass this data to openerp

Comment: cannot encode the image when i printed the return type of image it returns as instance type why it returns as instance and how to return it as binary data

Comment: Thanks sinoj for great...I want to have reverse of above question. I want to read image from xml rpc of openerp.  I have created custom module in openerp v7 and I want to fetch value of that module in my website using django. I am able to fetch all text field, but not able to get image. While fetching image (binary field) it gives value probably b64encoded. I don't know to make that image visible without storing image data. Is there any direct way to access image url of openerp module. Can you please guide me ? Thanks for your time and help.